# Can't install FacultyStaffDirectory on Plone 4.1

Tags: upgrade, plone, product

I am using Plone 4.1 and FacultyStaffDirectory 3.0. My buildout failed with an error (archetypes.schema < 2.1) so I pinned archetypes.schemaextender = 2.0.3 and I was able to install the FSD 3.0. However, when I try to activate it from the Add-ons page I get the following error:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
Module Products.CMFQuickInstallerTool.QuickInstallerTool, line 575, in installProducts
Module Products.CMFQuickInstallerTool.QuickInstallerTool, line 512, in installProduct
  __traceback_info__: ('FacultyStaffDirectory',)
Module Products.GenericSetup.tool, line 323, in runAllImportStepsFromProfile
  __traceback_info__: profile-Products.FacultyStaffDirectory:default
Module Products.GenericSetup.tool, line 1074, in _runImportStepsFromContext
Module Products.GenericSetup.tool, line 245, in getSortedImportSteps
Module Products.GenericSetup.tool, line 251, in getImportStepMetadata
Module Products.GenericSetup.registry, line 295, in getStepMetadata
Module Products.GenericSetup.utils, line 104, in _resolveDottedName
  __traceback_info__: Products.FacultyStaffDirectory.setuphandlers.unindexFSDTool
Module None, line 3, in <module>

ImportError: cannot import name DEFAULT_POLICIES
```

Answer (score 3):

Faculty Staff Directory needs to be updated for Plone 4.1.  The thing that needs changing is described in Plone's upgrade guide, here: http://plone.org/documentation/manual/upgrade-guide/version/upgrading-plone-4.0-to-4.1/updating-add-on-products-for-plone-4.1/use-generic-setup-for-defining-versioning-policies

At FSD's download page ( http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.FacultyStaffDirectory/3.0 ) you will find a contact email for the package authors to request they do this.

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely write to the WebLion team.

Answer (score 0):

We're in the process of updating FacultyStaffDirectory for 4.1. The 3.1 release will remove support for Plone prior to 4.0, so we're taking some time to clean up a lot of the cruft that's accumulated in the templates and setup code. SVN trunk is at http://weblion.psu.edu/svn/weblion/weblion/Products.FacultyStaffDirectory/trunk/ if you're feeling adventurous.